# load url programmatically with jQuery

Tags: jquery, ajax, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-dialog

This is a piggyback from my [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13446190/how-to-download-excel-from-jquery-get-ajax-request)

I was trying to download an excel after an AJAX get request, however, that is not feasible.

So now instead of

```
$.get("downloadExcel", {  
    'foo': 'bar'
});
```

I have a hidden url on the page like which I would like to click using jQuery UI when the user clicks a button on the modalbox. I will modify the parameters of the URL programmatically but I don't know how to load the click the URL using jQuery as if the user clicked on it:

```
<a href="downloadExcel?foo=bar" id="hiddenLink" src="display: none;"></a>
   $("#testexcel").dialog({
    autoOpen : false,
    draggable : false,
    resizable : false,
    modal : true,
    buttons: [{
         text: "Download File",
     click: function () {
            $("#hiddenLink").click();   //this doesn't work                       
            jQuery(this).dialog( "close" );
            return true;  
         }
     }]                        
 });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to do that.

Instead, you can just write `location.href = someUrl;`.  As long as that URL returns the appropriate headers, the browser will show a save dialog, as if you had navigated to that URL manually.

Answer (score 0):

Attempting to click a hidden link is more of a "hack" than a solution, and I'd suggest avoiding it.

Instead, you may want to use jQuery to create a hidden iframe on the page, which will allow you to let the user download a file while staying on the same page.

```
$('<iframe />', {
    src: 'downloadLink.html',
    style: 'display:none'
}).appendTo('body');
```

Answer (score 0):

As you've set the display style to hidden, it's likely that jquery cannot find the control on the page.

Try wrapping the link within a div tag that has the display style set to hidden.